# Spring + Maven: separate property files for unit tests and integration tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring, maven-2, properties

I'm using Spring 2.5.6 and building my project with Maven 2.2.1. We use `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` beans in Spring to load up properties for configuring things like the database. Pretty standard stuff. We also have two different sets of tests: unit tests and integration tests.

I would like to be able to use different property files to configure things like database url differently for the two different types of tests. For example, I want unit tests to use the `localhost` database and integration tests to use the `mydatabase.example.com` database.

I have tried several variations where I place the property files in separate subdirectories (one for unit tests and one for integration tests). From there, I've tried things like using the `additionalClasspathElements` tag for the `maven-failsafe-plugin`, but that didn't seem to work at all. I tried using the `maven-antrun-plugin` to copy the files into `target/classes`, but that didn't get triggered when I ran `mvn verify -Dtest=sometest`.

I also tried using `systemPropertyVariables` in maven to set a property called `buildEnvironment`, which I then tried to reference in my Spring bean definition:

```
<property name="locations">
  <value>classpath:${buildEnvironment}/my-test.properties</value>
</property>
```

But Spring refused to resolve `${buildEnvironment}`. At this point I'm out of ideas. I'm sure there's a nice, straightforward way to do this, but I can't figure it out.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen this related question with a different answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076466/maven-using-different-spring-properties-for-integration-tests

Comment: I'm also unable to get PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to see resources added with additionalClasspathElements. Does anyone have any idea why that doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could enable resource filtering and create maven properties:

```
<build>
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
  </resources>
</build>

<properties>
   <buildEnvironment>yourValue</buildEnvironment>
</properties>
```

${buildEnvironment} in your Spring config will then be resolved to "yourValue" (assuming it is under src/test/resources/)

Comment: This kind of works, although you have to use <testResources> instead of <resources> if you want to work for the test phases.
Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a way to set the property differently for integration tests vs unit tests without using profiles. That's acceptable, but not really what I was hoping for. :)